# Is there something wrong with our Captcha keys?

Tags: support, bug, captcha

[image: Captcha messed up]

Sometimes this happens, but why?  Are my eyes messed up?  Is there something wrong with Tim Stone's noggin?

Comment: You're reading it wrong -- the Data Explorer is setup to use right to left text processing to prevent spammers.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy And sometimes it tricks you with left to right!

Comment: Is "Tin Post" Tim Post's robot assistant?

Comment: @jonsca That's what he *wants you to think.*

Comment: Ohhhh, so is "Tim Post" Tin Post's human assistant??

Comment: ... you do mean Tim *Stone*, right?

Comment: @jonsca Tim Post edited my question to hide his *seekret!*

Comment: @hichris123 That's what Tim Post *wants* you to think... and again he's edited my question!  I've said too much!

Comment: This makes so much sense! You *are* Tim Post (or is it Tin Post?)

Comment: Yeah, Tin Stone would make more sense.  I figured that you just meant that any malfunction was Ti{m,n} Post's fault.

Comment: @hichris123 As I said, I've said too much... muahahaha!

Comment: WHAT IS HAPPENING HERE?!

Comment: @TimPost Like you don't know ;)

Comment: @TimPost I thought we all agreed at the hearing that weekends were still fair game.