# Who ate my rep changes on Area 51 (again)?

Tags: support, reputation, area-51, top-bar

Over the last week or so, the official top bar has returned to Area 51.  It was there briefly a few months back, but seems to have returned for good.  Definitely a positive, as I have always welcomed our new top bar overlords.

The rep dropdown (of yore) was the only way to see new reputation changes on Area 51, though.  Since the Area 51 reputation tally is not integrated with the rest of the SE ecosystem and there is no designated area on the Area 51 profile for recent rep changes, I'm down to the old abacus for keeping track of changes.  Having this reputation information may seem trivial, and it is, but I do use the growth in number of new followers as a cue to check on my proposals.

I certainly don't think it's worth anyone's efforts to crowbar the old Area 51 system into the new top bar, and I understand all of the issues in [Area51 Reputation changes do not show up in the new Top Bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211245/area51-reputation-changes-do-not-show-up-in-the-new-top-bar), but is there any way to monitor these rep changes in the meantime, or could we just get the old rep dropdown back again for a time, like it had been up until last week?

<sup><sup><sup>I'm not a begging person, but any hint of an Area 52 would be nice, too.</sup></sup></sup>

Comment: Hrm. Yeah, there isn't really an easy way to restore that functionality in the same way as it existed on A51. How about I link the usercard in the topbar to the Reputation tab of the user profile instead of the default Info tab? At least that way you'd have quick access to the breakdown of all rep changes.

Comment: @AnnaLear That would be awesome.  Maybe I've missed it all of these years, but if that's actually available, I could just bookmark it.

Comment: Okay, I totally forgot that it had the old style with the tabs up top, I found the right area.

Comment: I did. They were *delicious*.

Comment: @TimStone I blame [Tin Stone](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228540/is-there-something-wrong-with-our-captcha-keys#comment749341_228540), then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of the next build, the user card we show in the top bar will link to the Reputation tab on your profile.

That's about the best we can easily do with the current system. It won't notify you of changes, but you'll have one-click access to the breakdown page.

Comment: I appreciate it.  I'm sure others will be happy as well.

Comment: @jonsca but [others aren't happy about it](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/14118/i-dont-want-to-look-at-my-reputation-on-a51-but-the-topbar-makes-me) :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard If it took him a week to notice, he's just not enough of a hard-core A51 fan to matter ;)