# Area51 topbar links to reputation tab

Tags: bug, area-51, top-bar

Normally clicking on the badges/reputation/avatar image of the top-bar links to the info tab of the own profile.

Lately [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) also got the new top-bar but it links to the reputation tab of my profile. That can't be right, right?

Comment: It was introduced as a patch fix: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228719 (since incorporating the top bar into A51 hid all rep changes there now)