# Change the profile link in top bar from the reputation tab to info tab in Area 51

Tags: feature-request, area-51, top-bar

[image: top]

When I click on my profile link on the top bar in Area51 it takes me to the reputation tab of my profile.

> http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/1/username?tab=reputation

[image: rep]

I think its more appropriate to show the info tab which is a summary of the user profile than the reputation tab.

> http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/1/username?tab=stats

[image]

Comment: Better yet, remember the last active tab but guess it's too much to ask :)

Comment: See also [area51-topbar-links-to-reputation-tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229027/)